# How to get notified when new document is added to a certain collection on MongDB using its .NET driver?

Tags: .net, mongodb

I have a background service which continue adding new document to Mongodb, in my UI application, I'd like to be notified when a new document is added so that I can update my UI. Going through their API documentation, doesn't seem like there exist an event for me to subscribe on database change. How do I achieve this using their .NET driver ?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/) can help you. I don't know exactly which is the best approach, but i think you can try to build a listener for your collection on an separate thread using the method linked above.